# Mapping keys from dictionary to values in cases where column being mapped contains a larger string

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following keys that pertain to "London" as the value. The problem I am running into is that I want to check if column values contain my key value. So the postal code values should map to 'London" however they are currently mapping to "All Other".

In other words, postal code 'SW4 7SS' has "SW4' in it and therefore should map to 'London' however, it is currently being mapped to 'All Other' with my code.

I only have a mapping available for the current keys in the dictionary. Please advise on how to do so with pandas.

```
postal_code= {'SE10':'London',
'SW4':'London',
'SW9':'London',
'SW18':'London',
'   ': 'All Other'
}
```

```
Postal Code
SW4 7SS
SW4 6QD
SW4 7UD
```

```
df['Region']=df['Postal Code'].map(postal_code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join the `dict.keys` by `|` which is the `or` operator in regular expression. Then use `Series.str.extract` to extract these values from your column. Finally use `Series.map` to map the values with your dict:

```
regex = '|'.join(postal_code.keys())
df['Region'] = df['Postal Code'].str.extract(f"({regex})")[0].map(postal_code) 

  Postal Code  Region
0     SW4 7SS  London
1     SW4 6QD  London
2     SW4 7UD  London
```